# File, Save As for iPhone and Android

Tags: android, iphone

I have an application written in HTML5 that uses localstorage.  The user should be able to play this game in airplane mode, but right now it goes to my website to load the page.

Q: How do I save a web page onto a mobile device so that it doesn't require going to the Internet to dl it first?

Is the answer different for iPhone vs. Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a mixture of `DOMApplicationCache` and html5 web storage.

`DOMApplicationCache` is for storing files, like images and `JS` files. Info can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html)

web storage, in form of `LocalStorage` and `SessionStorage`, is for storing key/value pairs. That is pure data. There is also `WebSQL` that is like `SQLite`.

info on `LocalStorage` and session storage [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html)

Note that there are file-size limits, which vary on `Android` and `iOS` devices.

Comment: Also to note - you WILL have to visit the site first, but with a proper cache manifest file you only need to visit the home page (which could be the title screen of your game)

Comment: This link talks about using something called a data url:

Comment: http://blog.clawpaws.net/post/2007/07/16/Storing-iPhone-apps-locally-with-data-URLs

Comment: DataURL would work - you can even write them in CSS files, but is overly complicated. Why use a Base64 converter when you can just list the files and images in a file?